# I need a type for a graphql property that could be two 2 types

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-schema

So I have some code like the following:

```
input Data {
  activityValue: Int
}
```

But I need it to be something more like

```
input Data {
  activityValue: Int | String!
}
```

I know in typescript, even though frowned upon you can use `any` or `number | string`. Is there anything like this in graphql?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real such thing as multiple types in the GraphQL specification. However, `Unions` can fit your needs.

From the specification:

> GraphQL Unions represent an object that could be one of a list of GraphQL Object types, but provides for no guaranteed fields between those types.

That means that Unions can include types but no scalars or lists.

For example, a union can be declared like this:

```
union Media = Book | Movie
```

And then be used as a type:

```
type Query {
  allMedia: [Media] # This list can include both Book and Movie objects
}
```

Example is taken from [Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/unions-interfaces/).

If you want to check in your query if you have some type of the Union type, then you need to do that with inline fragments.

```
query Test {
  singleMedia(id: 123) {
    name
    ... on Book {
      author
    }
    ... on Movie {
      musicTitle
    }
  }
}
```